# How can I add the checkbox value into the firebase? it always turn to undefined

Tags: angularjs, checkbox, undefined

```
HTML
<div class="form-group"  ng-controller="AddPostCtrl" >
<label for="availability">Availability:</label></br>
<label>Monday:
<input type="checkbox"  ng-init="article.disabled=false" ng-true-
value="true"
ng-false-value="false"
ng-model="article.disabled">
</label><br/>

{{disabled}}
</div>

APP.JS

var value1 = $scope.article.disabled;

console.log(value1);
firebase.database().ref('tutors/'+uid).set({Monday:value1}).then
(function(ref)
{

$location.path('/home');
});
```

Hello I want to save to my firebase the value of my checkbox but it requires to click all the checkboxes before it will save because if I not click it the output was error because of the undefined value from the checkbox. please help me.

Comment: Hey, to you have your value1 when you console.log it? What do you see? try typeof value1 and see whats the type. If what you are trying to upload is undefined there will be an error so you have to make sure your params are correctly initialized.

Comment: I seen undefine value, can you explain more briefly?

Comment: So your problem is not with Firebase. The value is undefined to begin with. I am not sure what framework you are using. The syntax seems all over the place to me. I'm not familiar with angular. If your html and JS are in separate files, make sure you import your .js in html. Also, make sure you are really accessing your element. try var value1 = $scope.article and console.log(value1). You should see the element. If you do, then your check box mechanism is not correctly configured. This is my best shot without knowing angular and its syntax. Cheers

Comment: Try `firebase.database().ref('tutors/'+uid).set({Monday:value1 || false})`. Boolean variables default to undefined (just like all other variables) so you either need to initialize it to false or use a test when sending the value to your DB.

Comment: Thanks lex and to others commentors. I finally solve my problem :) Godbless you all.